# Load a View's background image based on a Property

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I am trying to set the background image of my view controller based on a property I set while it is initialized in the first layer of a navigation controller. In other words, before I tell my navigation controller to push the new view controller.

instead of manually typing in a bunch of if statements, I'm trying to find a way to do this automatically - I've tried this but it doesn't seem to work:

```
NSString *backgroundImageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"artistbackground%i.png",_artistID];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"@\"%@\"",backgroundImageName]]];
```

The string would correspond to the image title in my support files.

This hasn't been working does anyone have any other methods for handling this?

Thanks!!

Comment: how are the images named? that crazy quoting stuff does not make sense at all. Who names images like `"artistbackground1.png"`? INCLUDING the `"` Your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: Maybe you need some education about string literals. `@"foobar"` creates a NSString with the content `foobar`. Neither the `@` nor the `"` are part of the string. They are just there so the compiler knows that is has to create a `NSString` object out of the string literal you wrote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
NSString *backgroundImageName = [[NSString alloc]initWithFormat:@"artistbackground%i.png",_artistID];

self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:backgroundImageName]];
```

Comment: That unfortunately won't work as the image name must be quoted

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser: first time i hear this. Try it out, you won't be dissapointed :)